# Entity Framework Core self-referencing Map

Tags: entity-framework-core, data-annotations, blazor-server-side

I am using EF Core in my Blazor Server project. I have an entity called *Lesson*. A *Lesson* can have one or more prerequisite *Lessons* that must be completed before it is accessible.

I would prefer to use data annotations to accomplish setting up this relationship if possible.

Is the (redacted) approach below correct?

```
    public class Lesson : EntityBase
    {
        public List<LessonPrerequisiteLesson> PrerequisiteLessons { get; set; }
    }

    public class LessonPrerequisiteLesson : EntityBase
    {
        public int LessonID { get; set; }
        public int PrerequisiteLessonID { get; set; }
   
        [ForeignKey("PrerequisiteLessonID")]
        [InverseProperty("PrerequisiteLessons")]        
        public Lesson PrerequisiteLesson { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: Nothing weird here, but correct? I don't know. The proof of the pudding... Can you write your business logic using this model and does it store the data as you expect?

Comment: Gert- Thanks for the affirmation. I guess by "correct" what I meant was is it syntactically correct and will it work to create the desired schema. I'm very early on in this project, so it will be some time before I have a chance to actually test it in action. At the end of the day, what I need it to do is provide me with a list of lessons that are prerequisites for a given lesson. Sounds like I'm on the right track. Thanks again.

Comment: You also need a FK relationship for LessonId, similar to what you have for PrerequisiteLessonID.

Comment: PJS- I was under the impression that the annotations for foreign keys aren't necessary if the field is named the same in both tables.